# Adjust x ticks for a hour column of a dataframe in plotly

Tags: python, graph, plotly, linegraph, xticks

[Plotted using Autoplotter in jupyter where hours are in counts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qx2YW.jpg)[plot of Timestamp Vs Temp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtePM.jpg)

I have a csv file, that contains a column called hours. While plotting that in x axis for line graph in plotly , it is getting represented in the form of counts like

0K, 50K,………..250K. The frequency seems to be 1

Is there any way to adjust the ticks according to timestamp?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: does that mean hours is a continuous number, i.e. 240 is effectively 10 days?

Comment: Hi Rob. I have a column named hous: where the hour ranges from 9- 18 hrs. I have used a dash called Autoplotter in jupyter. There I got the hours as counts in 0K, 50 K.

Comment: Hi Rob. I have a column named hous: where the hour ranges from 9- 18 hrs. I have used a dash called Autoplotter in jupyter. There I got the hours as counts in 0K, 50 K. Now on writing the code , I could achieve the actual hour value but the lines are straight. I am not achieving a proper plot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- you describe hours in range unto 250k, so have simulated the same
- you can simply convert this to number of nanoseconds since epoch to use a timestamp axis
- have plotted both on same figure with two x-axis to demonstrate

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "hours": range(1, 250 * 10 ** 3 + 1, 100),
        "value": np.linspace(1, 10, 2500) * np.random.uniform(0.9, 1.1, 2500),
    }
)
px.line(df, x="hours", y="value").update_traces(name="raw", showlegend=True).add_trace(
    go.Scattergl(
        x=(df["hours"] * 60 * 60 * 10 ** 9).astype("datetime64[ns]"),
        y=df["value"] + 2,
        name="epoch",
        xaxis="x2",
    )
).update_layout(xaxis2={"anchor": "y", "domain": [0.0, 1.0], "side": "top"})
```

[image]

Comment: Hi@Rob Raymond. Thanks a lot for the reply. I really appreciate your effort. I just have a small question, so in my dataset , the hour column ranges from 3hrs to 24 hrs. This axis would be the x axis and y axis I would plot voltage and temperature.  

Just to reframe my question: I am trying to plot a line graph using plotly. But when I am plotting hour column in x axis, inspite of showing the real hour column it is showing me the counts as 0 K,50K,…. 250 K.

Comment: provide some sample code and data.  I can't see how 24hrs would be 250k in any units

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation, you specify the dtick field of the xaxis to 3600000 msec in the layout.

```
xaxis=dict(
    tickformat="%-H",
    dtick=3_600_000,
),
```

[plotly documentation on xaxis properties](https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/xaxis/)

> If the axis `type` is "date", then you must convert the time to milliseconds.